# How to get rid of black curve lines

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, selection-tools, select

[image]Anyone please help me to deal with these lines, I don't know how these lines gets formed.I simply want to get rid of them. You can see those short random lines selected in the image.I way a way to fix them.
[image]

Comment: those lines are caused by some topology problems, look closer to those areas, go to edit mode, x ray mode and look closer, can you add screen of what you will see? There are probably not connected vertices, flipped normals or missing faces

Comment: You're currently in x-ray mode Does pressing ALT-Z get rid of them?

Comment: nope ALT-Z didn't work.

Comment: I added one more screen, hope this helps to get a clear view about my problem.

Comment: well I got the way, I guess I have to delete those vertices. THanks for helping me!